# how do I track resource usage for a process?

Tags: python, linux

I was trying to get the resource usage for a single process, a python py file, from its initialization to termination. I used ps and top, but it did not give me how much resource this process consumed from birth to death. is there any way I can track a resource usage of a single process which will run about 5 seconds and dies? Thank you!

Comment: Different units. CPU usage is a time-snapshot, RAM is a time snap-shot. You could mathematically integrate it over time, or sample it and take an average. But still a different unit, % seconds, or MB seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582336/608639) More generally, [profile a python process site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=profile+a+python+process+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score -1):

it's very easy to make profiler for your app

1. `sudo apt install htop`
2. `htop`
3. `find your process name`

hope it's working, i'm new in programming

Comment: i prefer HTOP than TOP